Driving electromagnets from 3 phase DC motor driver
Extremely amateur hobbyist here. Had an idea for a present to make for my wife but wanted to check if I was on the right track before I purchased the parts.
Essentially I want to make what amounts to a magnetic stir plate. My initial idea was to stick some magnets to a fan or DC motor and just spin it to spin the stir bar, but that got me thinking; a motor is essentially a rotating magnetic field anyway. It seems silly to use create a rotating magnetic field to move an axel to then spin a magnet to create a rotating magnetic field.
If I were to arrange 3 electromagnets in a triangle pattern and drive them with a 3 phase motor signal would that effectively spin a magnet? It doesn't need to be fast, as this is purely decorative.
Would this work? Is this the better way, or is there a better option?

the stick would probably get dragged in a triangular path, unless attached to an axle in the middle

Hmm that is a fair point... Would I have to drive magnets in pairs do you think?

I have no idea how it would behave ... I just expect unpredictable results unless proven otherwise

decorative you could spin the needle of a compass.

If you want to DIY the motor it's doable BUT there are a large number of motors available that you could use. One with a gearbox is liable to best suit, to get a low enough stirring speed. We can answer questions on that if you wish - NOT on where to buy one but re motor characteristics, speed control etc,  That would need to be a new question.

Sure, it should work -- you've just invented the stepper motor. More electromagnet poles would make for smoother motion. In fact, you might try a stepper motor driver for the phased signal source.
Here's a more elaborate motor, with fancy field pieces that smooth motion.

making a stir bar with 16 poles could be trickly

Are you implying the poles would not cooperate? ;-)

I suggest it's more like a brushless DC motor.


It seems silly to use create a rotating magnetic field to move an axel to then spin a magnet to create a rotating magnetic field.

Not necessarily silly. Making an efficient motor with reasonable torque is not trivial, especially if a large air-gap is involved.
The problem is getting sufficient B field across an air-gap. The H field to do it, Amps/m, gets more expensive in terms of current - so power supply size and heating of the coils - as the air-gap increases.
Strong permanent magnets will get you a good field at a distance. You can then spin an array of them with a conventional efficient motor.
There's a stage in trash separation where conductive objects are flung out of a waste stream, by effectively making them the armature of a large motor. The travelling magnetic field used to propel them tends to come from a roller with permanent magnets embedded in it, being spun by a normal motor, rather than directly with coils.
Of course, this is about pleasing your wife, not about efficiency. Making the motor would probably get you more brownie points than an engineering solution. 'Decorative' implies you need little or no torque, so go for it.
